# Show image in ajax load doesn't work in chrome

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, asynchronous

i'm done a sync ajax request and i would like to show a image

```
<div id='loadingmessage' style='display:none'>
    <img src='images/ajax-loader.gif'/>
</div>
```

the javascript with the request

```
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                beforeSend : function(){
                $('#loadingmessage').show(); // show image..
                },
                url: "get_surrounding.php",
                data: SendData,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                async: false
            }).done(function (data2) {
               $('#loadingmessage').hide(); // hide image
               newPopup('show_surrounding.php',data2);
            });
```

this works in firefox but doesn't in chrome, any workaround?

Comment: Create a JSFIDDLE That demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 1):

just load it before the ajax call.

```
$('#loadingmessage').show();
$.ajax(...);
```

Comment: hmm, probably something else going on then. if you could set up a jsfiddle it'd be pretty easy to track it down.